# Hide button text in phone mode - Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am making an application in which I would like to hide the button text in order to save valuable space in the "phone mode". All the buttons have icons, so that should be enough.

I would like to have a pure css solution, but I can not come up with anything.

This is what a button looks like:

```
<button type="submit" name="btnSave" id="btnSave" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="icon-save"></i> Save</button>
```

I would like to add that it could also be an:

```
<a class="btn btn-warning"><i class="icon-trash"></i> Delete</a>
```

So basicly, if the responsive's mode is phone, all the text inside the .btn selector should be hidden. But the icon needs to remain.

I've tried `text-ident`, but that also hides the icon.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'd use the built-in twitter bootstrap class `.hidden-phone`.

```
    <button type="submit" name="btnSave" id="btnSave" class="btn btn-primary">
           <i class="icon-save"></i> <span class="hidden-phone">Save</span>
    </button>
```

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive

Comment: Is this W3C valid for <a > < /a> as well? If that's the case it would be perfect.

Comment: Yes, you can put span tags inside of an `a` tag

Answer (score 5):

In bootstrap 3 the `hidden-phone` class was [changed](http://getbootstrap.com/migration/) to `hidden-xs`. Matter of fact, `hidden-` can now be used with other device size prefixes such as `lg`, `sm` etc...

Answer (score 3):

For Bootstrap 4 you can use [display property](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/). As such, the classes are named using the format:

```
.d-{value} for xs
.d-{breakpoint}-{value} for sm, md, lg, and xl.
```

So your code should look like this:

```html
<button type="submit" name="btnSave" id="btnSave" class="btn btn-primary">
    <i class="icon-save"></i> <span class="d-none d-sm-inline">Save</span>
</button>
```

The text will disappear for extra small(xs) screens:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want?

```
<button type="submit" name="btnSave" id="btnSave" class="btn btn-primary">
    <i class="icon-save icon-white"></i>
    <span class="hidden-phone">Save</span>
</button>
```

Make sure you've included `bootstrap-responsive.css` if its not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a simple CSS rule like this :

```
@media screen and (max-width: 576px) and (min-width: 0px) {
  .desktop-only {
    display: none;
}
```

and then

```
   <button type="submit" name="btnSave" id="btnSave" class="btn btn-primary">
           <i class="icon-save"></i> <span class="desktop-only">Save</span>
    </button>
```